# Do browsers cache JSON

Tags: json, browser-cache

I want serve a JSON from a storage bucket. The JSON data will be updated periodically, but the URL will remain the same (I don't want to have to redeploy my site with an updated URL every time the JSON is updated). But I know that if this was CSS I would have problems with the browser caching the file and not fetching the updated data. Do browsers cache JSON like they do CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Caching related headers and (how they are handled) work for all HTTP resources. The file type isn't relevant.